# iOS Code Not Running When Method Called From Other Class

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, delegates

I have a custom UITableViewCell xib that has two buttons on it.  An edit button, designed to pass the info for that cell into a new view controller is the one I am currently having issues with.  I create a property for the TableViewController in my custom cell, and hook up the button to this code:

```
-(IBAction) editItem {
    self.itemsList = [[TheItemsList alloc] init];
    [self.itemsList editItem];
    NSLog(@"EDIT");
}
```

Inside TheItemsList I have this code:

```
-(void)editItem {
    NSLog(@"EDITAGAIN");
    EditItem *detailViewController = [[EditItem alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditItem" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.selectedCountry = self.selectedCountry;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    detailViewController.therow = indexPath.row;
    //Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    
    // Push the view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

The console prints my NSLog for each method, but the view does not push.  This code was previously used in the didSelectForIndexPath part of the table view, so I know that the view controller it is pushing is fine, I just can't figure out what is going on here.

UPDATE:

I have it SOMEWHAT working, emphasis on the somewhat.

ItemCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TheItemsList.h"
@class TheItemsList;
@class ItemCell;
@protocol ItemCellDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)editTheItem:(ItemCell *)theCell;
@end

@interface ItemCell : UITableViewCell
@property (assign) id <ItemCellDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *itemName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *itemPrice;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *itemAisle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *thumbnail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TheItemsList *itemsList;



@end
```

.m

```
#import "ItemCell.h"
#import "EditItem.h"
@implementation ItemCell
@synthesize itemName = _itemName;
@synthesize itemAisle = _itemAisle;
@synthesize itemPrice = _itemPrice;
@synthesize thumbnail = _thumbnail;
@synthesize itemsList, delegate;
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}
-(IBAction) editItem {
    [self.delegate editTheItem:self];
}


@end
```

Now, in the TableView

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ItemCell.h"
@class ItemCell;
@protocol ItemCellDelegate;
@interface TheItemsList : UITableViewController <ItemCellDelegate>
```

.m

```
-(void)editTheItem:(ItemCell *)theCell {
    NSLog(@"EDITAGAIN");
    EditItem *detailViewController = [[EditItem alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditItem" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.selectedCountry = self.selectedCountry;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    detailViewController.therow = indexPath.row;
    //Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    
    // Push the view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

What I'm running into is two problems.

## 1, the first item in the tableview doesn't do anything when the button is pressed.

## 2, the other rows will run code, but it only does it for the first row's data.

Comment: Edititem is in uitableviewcell class or tableviewcontroller class?

Comment: A newly created instance of `TheItemsList` won't have a navigation controller. Your cell should not push view controllers. It should could a delegate method on your table view controller which can push a new view controller

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok, so how would I go about doing that so that it can push the view controller when the Edit button is pressed?  IBAction editItem is on the cell, (void)editItem is on the tableviewcontroller

Comment: As I said, use a delegation pattern between your cell and your view controller.

Comment: @Paulw11 Check the OP update for how it is partially working, but not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the delegate pattern inside your UITableViewCell to delegate the button press back to the UIViewController which contains the UITableView using the cell.

In cellForRowAt:IndexPath you then retrieve the cell and set its delegate like `cell.delegate = self`. In the view controller you implement the delegate and handle the action.

In the cell you setup a delegate variable (var delegate: MyCellDelegate?) and inside the editItem function you make a call to the delegate like `self.delegate?.editItem()`

Comment: I've never done a delegate pattern before on here, so most of that went over my head, and I'm still using Obj-C as well

Comment: You basically create a protocol with one function in it. It's like a interface in java. Delegates are everywhere and are a important piece of the Obj-C and Swift language concepts. You surely have see some (e. g. UITableViewDelegate) https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Comment: Working on it but having problems, see OP for update.

Comment: I have it partially working, but having a few issues.

Comment: you can let the tableview get the indexpath of the cell passed to the delegate rather than using the selected row (something like `[tableview indexPathForCell: cell]`). Make sure to check if the delegate is set before calling it and lastly make sure you always set the delegate in cellForRowAt:IndexPath

Comment: Ok, I tried that, and it is now working for giving me correct entries on the 2nd and 3rd rows and beyond, but still nothing happens when I press the edit button on the top row of the tableview.  I have an NSLog added for the button, so I can confirm it is being pressed and running code, but for some reason the delegate doesn't get ran unless I push on one of the other rows.

Comment: I deleted the top entry from the data source to make sure it wasn't something to do with that.  The new top row is something that was working when it was the 2nd row earlier, but doesn't now.  So for whatever reason, it lets me press the button on the top cell, but won't run the code.

Comment: without having a look at the whole code I unfortunately cannot say what is wrong there. Maybe you are not correctly assigning the delegate to the cell? Or is it the button of the cell which is not working? Make two logs, one in the delegate function in the view controller and on in the button action inside the cell and see which one does not get fired

Comment: The one in the delegate function does not get called

Comment: in my cell for index:
`static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemsCell";
    ItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.delegate = self;

    if (cell == nil) {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ItemCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ItemsCell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ItemsCell"];
    }    // Configure the cell...
   
    return cell;
}`

Comment: Thoughts? Still stuck

Comment: Don't you see the problem? I see you are setting the delegate, then check if the cell is nil and if so, you register the cell in dequeue a new one. Of course that cannot work. First of all you should register the cell earlier e.g. in viewDidLoad and put the cell.delegate = self all the way to the bottom of your cellForRowAt so you can be 100% sure that there is a cell

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is basically because of this line

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

On clicking the button on the cell, it does not select the row necessarily. The button takes the touch. A way to solve this would be to find the NSIndexPath of the cell in which the button is present and then do your operations with it. A way to do is to use the cell reference that is being supplied from the `editAction` delegate

```
-(void)editTheItem:(ItemCell *)theCell
```

Replace `[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]` with `[self.tableView indexPathForCell:theCell]`